Consistency-proof of ZFC
According to Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem, ZFC cannot prove its own consistency. However, I have read that a stronger system S, i.e., a system that can fully represent/simulate/formalize ZFC and even go beyond it, can prove Con(ZFC) (of course, only if such a proof results from what S can do beyond ZFC). But this seems contradicted by the following example: ZF + Con(ZFC) can trivially prove Con(ZFC), but it is certainly not stronger than ZFC, since in ZF + Con(ZFC), unlike ZFC, the Axiom of Choice does not exist. How does this fit together?

There's no tension: "some theories stronger than ZFC prove the consistency of ZFC" doesn't in any way imply "every theory which proves the consistency of ZFC is strictly stronger than ZFC."
(In fact, the earliest interesting example of consistency strength illustrates this, with PA in place of ZFC: Gentzen proved that PRA + a particular further axiom $(*)$ proves Con(PA), but it's easy to find examples of sentences provable in PA but not in PRA+$(*)$.)

But if a system S is not stronger than ZFC it means two things: either it is as strong as ZFC, i.e. it can formalize precisely everything ZFC can in which case S = ZFC and Gödel 2 would prevent Con(ZFC) by S; or it is even weaker than ZFC, so it means some statements/inferences from ZFC are out of the scope of S but then its proof of Con(ZFC) would look ridiculous since maybe these very ZFC-formulas outside of S are inconsistent somehow.

@Pippen Or it's incomparable in strength with ZFC. (You're assuming, incorrectly, that theories are linearly ordered by strength.) And, indeed, pairs of theories like ZF+Con(ZFC) vs. ZFC (or PRA+$(*)$ vs. PA) are examples of exactly this phenomenon.

Ah, ok. So in general one can say: A system S can prove Con(S‘) iff S $\neq$ S‘ and  S $\not\subseteq$ S’and of course S $\vdash$ Con(S‘). (We assume the realm here where Gödel‘s theorems hold) Is that correct?

@Pippen Yes, but I think it's clearer to phrase it as: if $S$ is a subtheory of $S'$, and $S'$ is "appropriate", then $S$ cannot prove $Con(S')$.

Do you mean that PRA + $()$ proves Con(PA)?  If PRA + $()$ proves PA then surely it also proves every consequence of PA.

@ChrisEagle Derp, quite right - fixed!

Interesting observation: Let S be an arbitrary formal system. Then Con(S) can never be proven watertight. Because even if some S‘ proves Con(S) then we need Con(S‘) which will need some S‘‘ to prove it and its Con(S‘‘) etc. This leads to a regress (with the special case of circularity: Con(S) if S‘ if Con(S‘) if Con(S‘)) or an axiom like if we just postulate that Con(S) or Con(S‘) holds. In both cases we can never rule out efq and therefore never ~Con(ZFC). Gödel 2 does not touch this since he only talks about as if his systems are miraculously consistent anyway.

The use of "strength" here is with regards to consistency. Namely, $T$ is stronger than $T'$ if it proves the consistency of $T'$.
It doesn't mean that $T\vdash T'$, though.
Yes, this is confusing, since we use "strength" to mean that too sometimes. But we are talking about consistency, and so the strength is about that in this case.

That said, it's separately worth noting (per the OP's comments) that even for consistency strength we can have incomparable theories.

It might be also worth noting that although consistency strength and the amount of consequences are irrelevant in general, $\Pi^1_1$-consequences of a theory is somewhat related to the 'consistency strength' of a theory. (More precisely, proof-theoretic ordinal and $\Pi^1_1$-reflection strength. The latter is a $\Pi^1_1$-analogue of a consistency strength since $\mathsf{Con}(T)$ is equivalent to $\Pi^0_1$-reflection for $T$.)
